# Can I install 64 bit Ubuntu on my Intel Core i7 64bit PC?

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

I've an Intel Core i7 64 bit PC.

I've seen that Ubuntu 14.04 LTS has the following two versions..

ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso    (Intel 32 bit)

ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso   (AMD 64 bit)

Can I use `ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64.iso` to install Ubuntu onto my Intel 64 bit machine? Would I face any problem if I do this?

Or Should I install 32 bit version on my 64 bit pc? But if I do this, I think I won't be able to get the advantages of having a 64 bit pc..right?

What should I do now?

Please someone clear the fact (difference) of Intel x86 and AMD64.

Comment: Since you have Intel i7 processor, presumably you may have at least 4GB RAM. If so, go ahead, Buddy. Install 14.04 LTS 64 bit on your system. You would be amazed to see the performance of Ubuntu.

Comment: I agree the releases of the desktop iso's is confusing. I.E. I am troubled by the amd64 in the iso name. I too have a 64 bit machine running the intel i7 and 16gigs of ram. I guess the correct thing to do is install the `ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`. I will report how this goes

Comment: Confirmed: via install: the `ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso` also supports the Intel i7 chip [Intel Core i7-2600K Sandy Bridge Quad-Core 3.4GHz]